# An application with Flex, BlazeDS, Apache Tomcat, Java and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, flex3, blazeds

I want to make an application which involves technologies like Flex, Java, Hibernate, BlazeDS and the server is Apache Tomact 6.0. Can anybody help me in how to link the various files I have. I'm using Eclipse Europa currently. I want to know where to deploy the `.mxml` and `.class` files and where BlazeDS will come into all this.

Comment: Do you know how to work with each one of the technologies individually? If not, then you should learn the particular technology individually first. Once knowing them all, it would be nothing more than obvious how to fit them all together.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what You need step by step (unfotunately without hibernate), I won't copy & paste it ;)

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/livecycle/articles/blazeds_gettingstarted_02.html

There might be some hibernate integration in spring

http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-flex-webapp.html

Answer (score 0):

You can see this - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_hibernate.html
This is a tut for a demo app for exactly the same combo of technologies that you are asking for.